# MSP430 opcode table

Tags: assembly, msp430, opcode

What does "As" stand for in this MSP430 opcode table?[image]

I looked all over the place and did not find anything on the meaning of the abbreviation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.ti.com/sc/docs/products/micro/msp430/userguid/as_5.pdf table 5.1 explains that As is

> The bits representing the
> addressing mode used for the
> source

There is also Ad for the destination, and a whole number of other definitions which you should probably read if you try to understand the documentation.

Comment: I'm elegantly refraining from explaining what a search engine is.

Comment: I feel like this is one of those moments where a search engine wouldn't help. Small words like "as" tend to be filtered out.

Comment: I searched MSP430 as 01 00 10 and there it was.

Comment: Welp, guess I was wrong. I'm used to having these problems with certain things like typing in "sega genesis tas not working" and I get a bunch of tool-assisted speedruns (not the `tas` instruction like I wanted.)

Comment: It often helps if you can guess some terms which are likely to be present in the answer, not the question.

Comment: (I admit that my first comment might be a bit snarky, but really, it took me less than a minute, and I had never heard of this CPU before.)

Comment: It definitely was snarky, how should I know to type in 01 00 10 ? How did you know to type that @tripleee? typing in "MSP430 as" is not enough

Comment: Because those are the values for the field according to the table you posted.